# How to use Javascript to pull api, run calculations on pull data, and post results to webpage?

Tags: javascript, api

I am attempting to inject code into a webpage. Here is the situation:

api url: https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate

calculation: ((hashrate * 1249)/(27518 * 1000000)

then post calculation result to page.

Here is the javascript I have created so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var hashrate = (data);
            var miner_cost = ((hashrate * 1249)/(27518 * 1000000)
            $.html(miner_cost);
        }
    });
});
```

I have already created this successfully in python:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate'

BTC_Hashrate = requests.get(url).json()

BTC_Minercost_S15_28T = ((BTC_Hashrate *1249)/(28*39*2016*12.5*1000))

print BTC_Minercost_S15_28T
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Forgive me Javascript gods for I have sinned... I am a python user.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to alter the response of the API or do you want to communicate with the server that provides the API (i.e., does it “want” your response)?

Comment: I would like to alter the response of the API, for example if the response was 45977000744 I would want to change that to $2086.80 for the webpage. many thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery:

```
fetch('https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(hashRate => {
        const minerCost = (hashRate * 1249) / (27518 * 1000000)
        document.body.innerHTML = minerCost
    })
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jz4n2ydm/

Comment: Wow, that is amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah man, this is a killer solution! Hope you have a KICKASS Wednesday!!

Answer (score 0):

You may have some issue with jQuery. This one is working for me. I have changed the datatype to json.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://blockchain.info/q/hashrate',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var hashrate = (data);
        var miner_cost = (hashrate * 1249)/(27518 * 1000000);
        alert(miner_cost);
    }
});  });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response! It is helpful to see this jQuery method compared to the fetch. I am honored by your interest! Hope you have a kick ass Wednesday!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot alter the response of an API through JavaScript. (Think of what would happen if anyone could just write a script and change any data that is accessible through the web.)

In order to achieve your goal, you would have to configure the server of that API such that it can receive data sent to it via HTTP (i.e., it must not only handle a GET request to `/q/hashrate`, but also a POST request, possibly to some other route), and change its internal state accordingly. It can then return the updated data in subsequent GET requests.

But since you seem to have no control over the server, there is really nothing you can do to change the data.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have to pull the data and convert it into usable financial data. Thank you for your interest though! ;)

Comment: @cocoadreamboy I misunderstood your question then. I’m glad you still got your answer.